# zip image uploads

Tags: php

I'm writing a blog system (yes, I know I'm reinventing the wheel), and I want users to upload photos for their posts.

Up to now, in the form they filled to post a story, there was a field for the image, they selected and uploaded it.

Problem with that is that some stories may need more than one images, so I thought it would be easier to just let them upload a zip file containing the images, then the script unzips the contents, deletes anything non-white listed (.php files etc) and then goes ahead to process the images (create thumbnails, save the location in db etc..).

Is that a good practice?

If not, how can I handle the issue?

Comment: That seems reasonable. You could also allow FTP.

Comment: I mean, y'know, that *other crew over there with the snazzy site and the cool shoes* has an [Upload Media by Zip](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/upload-media-by-zip/) plugin.

Comment: @JaredFarrish they do have ftp access, since they are the site's owners, but I'm not too happy to have them change stuff via ftp..

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with consuming a zip if you're cautious and careful and make sure you diligently design it's consumer. You might even "enforce" a specific zip format that makes it easiest on you to handle security- and error-wise. I don't know. Take a look at that WP plugin to see how they work it, although they're not always the best when it comes to secure practices. Another option I suppose is to enable drag-n-drop from desktop to the browser window. That might also work, and reduce what the users do by a step.

Comment: For instance, there's this plugin: [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) Or nevermind, I see someone else linked to it already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With all modern browsers supporting uploading of multiple files through a single file input (http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_multiple.asp ) this is probably your best bet. And it's easier to deal with on the back end.

You should also have a look at this excellent JQuery plugin. It may come in useful
http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Well you say "all modern browsers" but as usual, IE fails to enter this category, rendering the best available solution useless.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has an official Zip library, [learn it](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) and use it! :)

Comment: this is what i saw, and it is enabled on my server, so I thought i'd go with it..

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow? You can take a zip upload and extract it wherever/however you want using this. You can also zip up files on your server.

Comment: We are saying the same thing. I found out about the Zip library, so I thought I could use it, so I came here to ask if that would be a good practice!

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I misread your question. I thought you were wondering how to do it. Yes, I Think it's good practice, why not :)

Answer (score 0):

You can upload more than one file with one upload form. Maybe add more files to the form with AJAX.

Other way: Let users upload their files to a media storage and then select the images for insertion while writing an article.